# media queries apparently not working on mobile devices

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a question on media queries.

My html is the following

```
<div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

my css is the following

```
.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .item {
        background-color: green;
    }

  }
```

I have the following line in index.html `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Now, if I reduce the size of the browser, I see the divs in green. If I use the Chrome device simulator for **iPhone6 plus**, I see the divs green. If I use other **iPhone plus** simulators I see the divs green.

BUT, if I install this code into an app server (a simple ASW S3 in this case), and I download the page on my **iPhone6 plus**, I see the divs in yellow.

Apparently the media query does not work properly. I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I am totally blind at the moment.

Comment: works fine if you works in local? And not when is on a web server? https://jsfiddle.net/6ubzn860/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the difference between max-width and max-device-width.

Here max-width is width of the target display area, e.g. the browser

and max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen

So based on your device iphone 6 plus your css should be like below for landscape mode

```
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width : 414px) 
   and (max-device-width : 736px) 
   and (orientation : landscape) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
{ }
```

and for portrait

```
@media only screen 
   and (min-device-width : 414px) 
   and (max-device-width : 736px)
   and (device-width : 414px)
   and (device-height : 736px)
   and (orientation : portrait) 
   and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) 
   and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I have done some analysis and found the cause, even if not the solution.

The web server where the site resources are hosted is an AWS S3 instance, let's say **http://my-site.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/**.

If I access my site directly from AWS S3 with the address `http://my-site.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` then everything works as expected, i.e. media queries work fine on mobile devices.

The domain I want to use to access the site is **mydomain.com**, which I have defined with ***GODADDY***.

Therefore I have defined a redirect rule in the GODADDY configuration so that it points the correct AWS S3 address. I use the option "Forward with masking" since I want to see **mydomain.com** on the browser bar.

If I access now the web site FROM A MOBILE DEVICE using the domain `mydomain.com` I see something different, the site looks like it is not using the css media queries. By the way, this happens only on mobile devices, on the browsers on PC or Mac everything works as expected.

Now I make a change in the **GODADDY** configuration. I use the option "forward without masking". Everything works as expected even on the mobile devices, even if I have to see in the browser bar the `http://my-site.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` address.

As I said at the beginning, this seems to be the cause of what I have experienced. No idea about a solution. I will post a more specific question, now that I know something more.